# Download bootstrapper exe path in msi

Tags: wix

I would like to assign a property path to the bootstrapper exe.

I've seen a few posts that show you can do it this way:

```
<MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile"...\Installer.msi" ...>
    <MsiProperty Name='CONFIGFILELOCATION' Value='[WixBundleOriginalSource]'/>
</MsiPackage>
```

But all the ways I found to download it in the product don't work.

I'm not sure if I create veriable with value [WixBundleOriginalSource] returns the path, because writing it to the txt file in the custom interface returns me [WixBundleOrginalSource] instead of the path.

I was trying use in custom action:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution:

```
<Property Id="CONFIGFILELOCATION"\>
<SetProperty Id="CONFIGFILELOCATION" Value="[CONFIGFILELOCATION]" Before="AppSearch">
     CONFIGFILELOCATION=""
</SetProperty>
```

I don't understand how value works in the end, because if you can do something else, it also works.